# What URL should I use for Amazon CloudFront content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, public, amazon-cloudfront

This has also been posted in the AWS forum. But it's languishing a bit (and I'm in a hurry to solve this problem).

**This question is with regard to a 'download' distribution, not 'streaming'.**

I've recently signed up and created an Amazon S3 bucket and then created an Amazon CloudFront (CF) distribution out of that bucket. Here's the relevant info:

```
Bucket Name: stella_media
Folder In Bucket: visia
```

Which results in a working URL (with public-read access) like this: http://s3.amazonaws.com/stella_media/visia/720_125M_Zero_Dark_Thirty.mp4

So you'll see that if you use the above URL (and you're not using Firefox) it loads the MP4 video. All the media in my bucket is set to public-read.

**My Problem Is With Access To The Same Content Via Cloudfront:**

And my CF distrubution has the following properties:

```
Delivery Method: download
Distribution Status: deployed
Price Class: US & Europe
State: Enabled
Domain Name: d2322fq9z81lph.cloudfront.net
```

However, when I use the URL provided to me when I setup my CF distribution on that bucket I get a "noSuchKey" error: http://d2322fq9z81lph.cloudfront.net/stella_media/visia/720_125M_Zero_Dark_Thirty.mp4

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>stella_media/visia/720_125M_Zero_Dark_Thirty.mp4</Key>
    <RequestId>5E2FA36884444757</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        HiphTLuv4P2tiJemBRNvIGsq8DRbSCMocdAvm4oto9NVnnKNHuDZWuFHz+xyCt6B
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

So ... exactly what URL am I supposed to be using to point to my video **OR** is there some sort of permissions setting that I've overlooked to make the content in my CF distribution public?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the benefit of any others that may come across this, I've figured this out.

Apparently CloudFront URL's **DO NOT INCLUDE THE BUCKET NAME**. So it would play out like so:

**S3 URL**
http://s3.amazonaws.com/stella_media/visia/720_125M_Zero_Dark_Thirty.mp4

**CloudFront URL**
http://d2322fq9z81lph.cloudfront.net/visia/720_125M_Zero_Dark_Thirty.mp4

Hopefully that helps anyone else from going out of their mind trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Also, could be an issue w/ use of capital letters in your bucket name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350957/amazon-aws-cloudfront-claims-no-such-bucket-exists

Comment: CloudFront is a CDN which just points to a root domain somewhere else. For S3, the actual root is: http://stella_media.s3.amazonaws.com/ but you can include the bucketname afterwards as an alias (which is what you have).